# Flutter: Passing Variables from CLass A to B to Class C

Tags: class, flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I have an app that I want to Pass variable review from Class A -> Class B -> Class C

The problem that I receive error that reviews variable is null

I do it normally like:

Class A:

```
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: = B(reviews: reviews,)
             )
```

Class B:

```
class B extends StatefulWidget {
final reviews;

B({this.reviews});
@override
_BState createState() => _BState();
}

body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: = C(reviews: widget.reviews,)
             )
```

Class C:

```
class C extends StatefulWidget {
final reviews;

C({this.reviews});
@override
_CState createState() => _CState();
}

body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: = Text(widget.reviews),
             )
```

I know there is must be better logic than this, can someone help me with it?

Comment: Check out Inheritedwidgets/provider

Comment: using provider or inherited widgets you can expose any object or value on an ancestor in the widget tree, and then access it directly in any of it's child using Provider.of<Object>(context) > in case of provider. This way you don't have to keep passing your variables all the way down your widget tree.

Comment: Make Use of InheritedWidgets